# How to create event handlers dynamically in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a draggable table for which I'm trying to drag a tr and I want to drop it to one of the droppable tables. 
The code is working as expected but I want to make this code dynamic. 
How can it be possible? Here is my code

```
jQuery('#pipeline_lead_card_table_1').droppable({ 
   tolerance: 'pointer',
   drop: function(event, ui) {   
    jQuery('#pipeline_lead_card_table_1 .pipeline_lead_card_table      
    tbody').append(ui.helper.children());
  }
}); 

jQuery('#pipeline_lead_card_table_2').droppable({ 
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  drop: function(event, ui) {   
    jQuery('#pipeline_lead_card_table_2 .pipeline_lead_card_table    
    tbody').append(ui.helper.children());
  }
}); 

jQuery('#pipeline_lead_card_table_3').droppable({ 
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  drop: function(event, ui) {   
    jQuery('#pipeline_lead_card_table_3 .pipeline_lead_card_table 
      body').append(ui.helper.children());
     }
  }); 

 jQuery('#pipeline_lead_card_table_4').droppable({ 
   tolerance: 'pointer',
   drop: function(event, ui) {   
     jQuery('#pipeline_lead_card_table_4 .pipeline_lead_card_table     
       tbody').append(ui.helper.children());
      }
  });
```

What I want to make this code dynamic as I don't know how many tables will be generated dynamically.

Comment: Would advise switching from ID Selector to Class selector. This way you can make more dynamic calls. You may also consider creating functions that apply Drag n Drop to a passed element. This way you can create dynamic elements and then initialize them for drag or drop.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already tried using class selector and also tried the code you provided. The problem in using class selector is that it only consider the first droppble element for dropping the element.

Comment: I have solved this problem by using  `.each` for all the dropable elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding upon my comment, you could simplify the code like so:

```
(function($) {

  function makeDrop($o) {
    $o.droppable({
      tolorance: "pointer",
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        $(".pipeline_lead_card_table tbody", this).append(ui.helper.children());
      }
    });
  }

  makeDrop($('#pipeline_lead_card_table_1'));
  makeDrop($('#pipeline_lead_card_table_2'));
  makeDrop($('#pipeline_lead_card_table_3'));
  makeDrop($('#pipeline_lead_card_table_4'));
})(jQuery);
```

No, if each of your tables has a Class attribute, E.G.: `can-change`, you could simplify the code even further:

```
(function($) {

  function makeDrop($o) {
    $o.droppable({
      tolorance: "pointer",
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        $(".pipeline_lead_card_table tbody", this).append(ui.helper.children());
      }
    });
  }

  makeDrop($('.can-change'));
})(jQuery);
```